# dynamically "hobby" checkbox checked according database value through different id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My Question: first time i click edit button then checkbox checked according database table value,and then second time i click other edit button then first time checkbox value not unchecked,i don't know what is mistake in my code.
please check my code.

Example: In Form Screenshot, when first edit button i click then checkbox value(like cricket,hokky,chess)checked, and after second edit button i click then checkbox value(cricket)checked,but problem is first time checkbox value(like cricket,hokky,chess) not unchecked, please help me,

**please check below screenshot:**

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6dlf.png)

**HTML Code:**

```
    <form id="crudform" method="post">
        <label>Hobby:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="cricket">Cricket
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="hokky">Hobby
        <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="chess">Chess
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
    </form>

<div class="table"></div>
```

[Database Table ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAPka.png)

**PHP Code:**

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hobby</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ ?>
                <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['hobby'];?></td>
                <td><button name="edit" data-id = <?php echo $data['id'];?> class="btn btn-info">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button[name=edit]").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    var hobbyss = [];
    $(":checkbox").each(function(index,element){
        hobbyss.push($(this).val());
    });


    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/interview/crud_checkbox/edit.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{id:id},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            var hobby = response.hobby.split(",");          // ["cricket", "hokky", "chess"]    

            $.each(hobby,function(index,element){
                if($.inArray(element,hobbyss) >= 0){
                    console.log($("input[value="+element+"]").prop("checked",true));
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, I don't see any checkboxes at least...

Comment: @jeroen  please check databse screenshot and registration form screenshot

Comment: My Question is very simple, my question is i click edit button and checkbox not checked according databse fetch value

Comment: And how do you expect anybody to help you when you post some code that is completely unrelated to your problem?

Comment: @jeroen please help me

Comment: Are you asking why the checkboxes in your private PHPMyadmin aren't checked from the user actions handled in your PHP/jQuery code ??

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette my question is: i click edit button and hobby not checked according hobby column value in database

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok... So I assume we're talking about the blue edit button (not the link in PHPMyadmin). You say that the "hobby" checkboxes should be checked according to the DB value on Ajax success? Is that it?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes exexcelity

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette   i say hobby" checkboxes should be checked according to the DB value on Ajax success

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer... There is something you should add: the markup of that cell where the checkboxes are. I'm busy at the moment... But add this info and someone will be able to answer. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette when you free then solve my probelm please,,,,please

Comment: **Add the markup of that cell where the checkboxes are**, please. You can copy/paste it **in your question** from your rendered page's [dev tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). Just one `tr` line is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Each time On edit button click your adding checked attribute but you forgot to remove checked attribute for previously checked checkbox. so you need to uncheck all checkbox on edit button click like below.

```js
$("button[name=edit]").click(function(){

 $('input[name=hobby\\[\\]]').prop('checked',false);
    
    //rest of your code here 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="crudform" method="post">
 <label>Hobby:</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="cricket" checked >Cricket
 <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="hokky">Hobby
 <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[]" value="chess" checked >Chess
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<button name="edit" data-id ="1" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
```